# Make a fake schedule if it doesn't exist in db

Tags: sql, mysql, schedule

I want to pull all the rows from a database for a month and if there are any rows in the beginning or in the end that are missing then I want to create fake rows, so every day there is a schedule that one has to follow. How can I detect missing rows or how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [how to fill up the missing dates ??](http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=155890)

> fill a calendar table use that as your
>   driving table (i.e. first one in your
>   select) and do a LEFT JOIN on it.

[Create and fill a calendar table](http://guelphdad.wefixtech.co.uk/sqlhelp/calendarfill.shtml)

Comment: but i would need to create 3 more tables to do that or is there other way around it without creating date table?